# How to redefine an element (df) of matrix using assign R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to redefine propperly elements of a multidimensional matrix using `assign` on R.

I tried this

```
lat = 3
lon = 3
laidx = 1:3
loidx = 1:3
OtherDF is a 3x3 multidimensional matrix, and each element is a large data frame

for (i in 1:12){

  assign(paste("STAT",i,sep=""),array(list(NA), dim=c(length(lat),length(lon))))

  for (lo in loidx){
    for (la in laidx){

    assign(paste("STAT",i,"[",la,",",lo,"]",sep=""), as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,otherDF[la,lo])))
    # otherDF[la,lo] are data frames


    } 
  }
}
```

First I created 12 empty matrix STATS1,STATS2 ,...,STATS12 (I need 12, one for each month)

Then I tried to fill them with elements of an other dataframe, but instead of filling it create a lot of new variables like this `STAT10[[1,1]]``

Some help please

Comment: The first assign statement is fine. Once you have that by calling `assign(paste("STAT",i,"[",la,",",lo,"]",sep=""),...)` you are creating a new variable and you are not accessing the one you already created.

Comment: But how can i access the one I already created ? Thanks @AGore

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10838/produce-a-list-of-variable-name-in-a-for-loop-then-assign-values-to-them

Comment: Generally using `assign` is frowned upon; there are usually better alternatives to solving problems in R. Plus `assign` only works with variable names `x[i]` is not a variable name, it's actually calling the function `[` with `x` and `i` as parameters. Anyway, it would be better to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the desired output so that a better strategy can be suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't provide your data, I made up some:

```
lat = 3
lon = 3
otherDF <- data.frame(A=1:3, B=4:6, C=7:9)
loidx <- 1:3
laidx <- 1:3
```

I avoid the nested for loops and the second `assign` statement with `expand.grid` and `sapply(iter(idx,by="row", function(x) otherDF[x$Var1,x$Var2])`.

```
install.packages("iterators")
for (i in 1:12){
    library(iterators)
    idx <- expand.grid(loidx,laidx)    # expands all combinations of elements in loidx and laidx
    assign(paste0("STAT",i), matrix(sapply(iter(idx, by="row"), function(x) otherDF[x$Var1, x$Var2]), ncol=3))
}
```

*I made some guesses on what you wanted based on your code*, so edit your original post if you wanted something different.

Comment: I edited the original post, otherDF was a multidimensional matrix too